# Can we push the new JSON node in existing JSON in apex?

Tags: json

Need to add New JSON in the existing JSON
For example I want to add filters in JSON of filter schema.

```
String str = '{"reportMetadata" : {'
+'"aggregates" : [ "RowCount" ],'
+'"currency" : null,'
+'"detailColumns" : [ "CUST_NAME", "CTSTESTCOVERAGE__TestCoverage__c.CTSTESTCOVERAGE__Class_coverage__c", "CTSTESTCOVERAGE__TestCoverage__c.CTSTESTCOVERAGE__Total_number_of_lines__c", "CTSTESTCOVERAGE__TestCoverage__c.CTSTESTCOVERAGE__Covered_Lines__c", "CTSTESTCOVERAGE__TestCoverage__c.CTSTESTCOVERAGE__Uncovered_Lines__c" ],'
+'"developerName" : "Test_Run_All_Test_Classes_Result",'
+'"groupingsAcross" : [ ],'
+'"groupingsDown" : [ ],'
+'"id" : "00O6A000002rWX4UAM",'
+'"name" : "Test Run All Test Classes Result",'


 +'"reportBooleanFilter" : null,'
    +'"reportFilters" : [ ],'
    +'"reportFormat" : "TABULAR",'
    +'"reportType" : {'
     +' "label" : "TestCoverages with Salesforce org",      '
    +'"type" : "CustomEntity$CTSTESTCOVERAGE__TestCoverage__c@CTSTESTCOVERAGE__TestCoverage__c.CTSTESTCOVERAGE__Salesforce_org__c"'
    +'}'
  +'}'
+'}';
```

In above JSON String I want to add filters in reportFilters. like :

```
 "reportFilters" : [ {
  "column" : "FK_NAME",
  "operator" : "equals",
  "value" : "Dev Sandbox"
} ],
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is to deserialize, then add the new data, then serialize:

```
Map<String, Object> root = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(str);
Map<String, Object> reportMetadata = (Map<String, Object>) root.get('reportMetadata');
List<Object> reportFilters = (List<Object>) reportMetadata.get('reportFilters');

// Add new filter to list
reportFilters.add(new Map<String, Object>{
        'column' => 'FK_NAME',
        'operator' => 'equals',
        'value' => 'Dev Sandbox
        });

String result = JSON.serialisePretty(root);
```

Note that when building JSON in Apex code, it is usually better to use maps or simple Apex objects to build up the data and then put the result through `JSON.serialise` rather than use lots of string concatenation. Makes the code more readable and also ensures the appropriate escaping (e.g. a double quote embedded in a string) gets done.